# Select @@Identity inside 'Using' statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, using

I am coding a `Sql-Server-ce` application in `C#`.

Recently I have been converting my code to use `using` statements, as they are much cleaner. In my code I have a `GetLastInsertedID` function which is very simple - it returns the last inserted ID. The working version is as follows:

```
    public static int GetLastInsertedID()
    {
        int key = 0;
        try
        {
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT CONVERT(int, @@IDENTITY)", DbConnection.ceConnection);
            key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not get last inserted ID. " + ex.Message);
            key = 0;
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Below is the code that does NOT work once I wrap it in `using` statements:

```
    public static int GetLastInsertedID()
    {
        int key = 0;
        try
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(DbConnection.compact))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT CONVERT(int, @@IDENTITY)", conn))
                    key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not get last inserted ID. " + ex.Message);
            key = 0;
        }
        return key;
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is `specified cast is not valid`. Although this error is usually self-explanatory, I cannot see why I would be getting it inside the second block of code, but not the first. This error occurs on the line `key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`.

What am I doing wrong with the second block of code?

Comment: "doesn't work" what do you mean? Does it throw an exception? If I had to guess I'd say something was being disposed prematurely.

Comment: Sorry, noob mistake for not posting error. It was `specified cast is not valid`. I have edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment! But anyway try to place a breakpoint at `key = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`, put the command on the watch window and check out what type is coming out. It seems that, for some reason it's not an int, despite the convert. Then you will be closer to figure out what's happening, maybe.

Comment: I will check that now. Any idea why using the `using` statement would suddenly change the datatype? As it works in the first block of code.

Comment: Why do you need to query the `@@IDENTITY` using a separate connection? Can't it be done where you do `INSERT`s?

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question, can you please tell me why you think it is a poor question?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I query @@IDENTITY hundreds of times so its easier to write `int id = GetLastInsertedID();`

Comment: In that case, write a separate function which executes `INSERT` statement and returns the identity value. for e.g `GetLastInsertedValueUsing("INSERT INTO......")` and replace `INSERT` statements with a call to `GetLastInsertedValueUsing("INSERT INTO......")`

Comment: Ugh, looking back at my questions from 4 years ago... please forgive me, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `@@Identity` will return **any last generated ID** from anywhere in SQL Server. Most probably you need to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead.

This shows your actual problem and design issue - you need to keep **Connection** and **Command** separate. **Connection** embeds transaction and though `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will work until connection is closed; **Command** can be created, used and disposed.

So you need method which accept `connection` and use it to obtain identity - something like this (didn't check it but think idea should be clear):

```
public static int GetLastInsertedID(DbConnection connection)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT CONVERT(int, SCOPE_IDENTITY())";
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn)) {
            return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not get last inserted ID. " + ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For working with connection you can create helper method like this:

```
public static SqlCeConnection OpenDefaultConnection()
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(DbConnection.compact);
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
...
using (SqlCeConnection conn = OpenDefaultConnection()) {
    //... do smth
    int id = GetLastInsertedID(conn);
    //... do smth
}
...
```

Comment: No Scope_identity() in SQL Server Compact

Comment: completely missed that, but pattern still usable

Answer (score 5):

From the [@@IDENTITY documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session.

I think your change now starts a new session for each using statement. Therefore @@IDENTITY is null.

Comment: Ah. So I cannot use a `using` statement in this fashion at all?

Comment: You'll have to do the insert and the @@IDENTITY in one and the same using statement.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, the reason that it doesn't work is not related to the `using statement`.

If you use a static class to do the operation of connecting database, like DBHelper. The problem will be caused by that you close the connection of database before you execute the `select @@identity` and when you execute `select @@identity`, you open it again. This executing sequence will cause that the return result of `select @@identity` is NULL. That is, you can not use `DBHelper.xxx()` twice for getting the automated ID, because every time you call `DBHelper.xxx()`, the process of the opening database and the closing database will be done.

I have a solution but it maybe not the best one. Instead of using `select @@identity`, you can use `select count(*) from xxx` to get the same result.

Hope that it can help you